# I'm not able to login after django version upgrade

Tags: django, cookies, authentication, django-login, django-upgrade

I'm trying to upgrade an old code from django 1.5 to 1.8 for a client. The project use `django.contrib.auth.views.login` to verify the login. the `urls.py` looks as follow:

```py
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^accounts/login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {'template_name': 'accounts/login.html', 'authentication_form': LoginForm}, name="login"),
    url(r'^accounts/logout/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout', {'template_name': 'accounts/logged_out.html'}, name="logout"),
)
```

Here is the `LoginForm` class:

```py
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(label=_("Username"), max_length=120)
    password = forms.CharField(label=_("Password"), widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    def __init__(self, request=None, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = request
        self.user_cache = None
        super(LoginForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
        password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')

        if self.request:
            if not self.request.session.test_cookie_worked():
                raise forms.ValidationError(_("Your Web browser doesn't appear to have cookies enabled. Cookies are required for logging in."))

        return self.cleaned_data
```

and here is the list of the middlewares:

```py
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',

    'apps.facebook.middleware.FacebookMiddleware',
)
```

Before the upgrade I was able to login, but after upgrading I'm no longer able to login. I got the following **non-field** error:

> Your Web browser doesn't appear to have cookies enabled. Cookies are required for logging in.

If I downgrade to django 1.5 I can login again. How can I solve the problem and why the login is not working in django 1.8.

Comment: Please show your `accounts/login.html` template and `LoginForm`.

Comment: Have you tried enabling cookies in your web browser?

Comment: Yes I tried but still the same problem. I think it's not related to browser since it works with django 1.5. I guess it's some security upgrade in Django, but I can't find out how to solve it.

Comment: Django introduced cookie-based sessions in 1.4 I believe; a 1.5 project may have some backwards compatibility to the pre-cookie era that is no longer supported. Could you post your middleware settings?

Comment: You haven't shown your `LoginForm`.

Comment: Are you calling `set_test_cookie` anywhere before calling `test_cookie_worked`? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/sessions/#setting-test-cookies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the cookie test from your login form, it isn't necessary. The check was removed from the [Django login form](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.8.9/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L122) in Django 1.7 ([release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/internals/deprecation/#deprecation-removed-in-1-7)).

You have CSRF protection enabled, which already ensures that cookies are enabled.

It's not clear why you are defining your own login form, instead of using the built in form. Using your own form means you hit problems like this, and miss out on new features like the [`confirm_login_allowed`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.8.9/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L169) hook.